# I have a semantic error on a program that goes up, then back down in python

Tags: python

So, I'm relatively new to python and I have this semantic error. I'm essentially trying to make a program that goes up to 50, then back down. This is not my full program in general but a part of it that I can't seem to solve. This is what I have done:

```
maxH = 50
current = 0

while True:
    if current < maxH:
        current += 1
    else:
        current -=1

    print(current)
```

I know that the clear error is that when the current becomes max, it subtracts by 1 and then the if statement is true again.

any help with an alternative way to get over this logic error would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you give some details on why you need this? To help with alternatives, this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your logic in two steps:

- incrementing until you reach the maximum
- decreasing until you are back to zero.

This will do the trick.

```
current = 0
maxH = 50

# Increment until current == maxH
while current < maxH:
    current += 1

# Decrement until current == 0
while current > 0:
    current -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ugly back of the napkin code, but the output is what you're looking for and can give you an idea how to avoid the problem.

```
maxH = 50
current = 0
flag= "yes"

while flag == "yes":
    if maxH > current:
        current+=1
        print(current)
    else:
        flag = "no"
        break

while flag == "no":
    current-=1
    print(current)
    if current == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to exit loop. so when current hits 50 it will execute the else statement bringing to 49 then since 49<50 it will add 1 and so on. a quick fix would be adding an if else statement so that when current == 50 exit the loop

```
maxH = 50
current = 0

while True:
   if current < maxH:
      current += 1
      print(current)
   elif current == 50:
       print(current)
       break    
   else:
       current -=1
       print(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
maxH = 50
current = 0
while True:
    while current < maxH:
        current += 1
        print(current)
    while current > 0:
        current -= 1
        print(current)
```

It will loop from 0 to 50 and back down endlessly.